# Extract the year in Velocity Template Language - Python

Tags: python, pycharm, velocity-template-language

I was referring to [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-file-and-code-templates.html) to print the author information as header on each python script. The document shows an example for printing the date information -

`# Created by ${USER} at ${DATE}`

This prints the entire date in `DD-MM-YYYY` format. However, I just need the `YYYY` part i.e. only the year. How can I do this?